# How to make SSL connection using JKS file in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

Trying to establish connection SSL from Java using below two approaches, trying to achieve either of one. Both approaches were getting errors please find the code and errors getting for it.

We have included https://github.com/gpotter2/SSLKeystoreFactories plugin to establish the connections

**Approach 1**

```
- SSLSocket s = SSLSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert(neHost, Integer.parseInt(port), 
Main.class.getResourceAsStream(Utilities.readGRCParameter("KeyStore", macro)), 
Utilities.readGRCParameter("KeyStore_password", macro)); 
s.startHandshake(); httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) this.httpURL.openConnection(); 
String authString = this.username + ":" + this.password; 
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()); 
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes); httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
StringBuffer responseHeader = getHttpResponseHeader(httpConn);
```

---

**Error is**

> Thread-2, handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected
>   error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the
>   trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty Thread-2, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:
>   fatal, description = internal_error Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert,
>   length = 2 [Raw write]: length = 7 0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50 ......P
>   Thread-2, called closeSocket() 7900 SOAP910 General error:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty

---

**Approach 2**

```
SSLServerSocket s = SSLServerSocketKeystoreFactory.getServerSocketWithCert(Integer.parseInt(port), Main.class.getResourceAsStream(Utilities.readGRCParameter("KeyStore", macro)), Utilities.readGRCParameter("KeyStore_password", macro)); 
s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites()); 
SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) s.accept(); 
ss.startHandshake(); httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) this.httpURL.openConnection(); 
String authString = this.username + ":" + this.password; byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()); 
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
 httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc); 
StringBuffer responseHeader = getHttpResponseHeader(httpConn);
```

---

Getting Error is

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
```

> done seeding SecureRandom Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA $CTRL$ Panic - Process terminated.

Please help me to get it worked with either of the approaches or provide any suggetions to get the ssl connection done.

Comment: There is no common algorithm available for establishing a SSL connection. Most likely it's a problem in your certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @We are Borg, seems certificate is valid, bcoz its working from soap Ui, when tried to implement in java, getting the above errors

Comment: Yes, it's not the validity of the certificate I am questioning, it's the algorithm used. A common algorithm is missing. Try to set the algorithm to one of the mentioned above and which is available.